# Changing android Button Color continuously

Tags: android, eclipse, button, colors

I have a simple button in my app.
I want do the following thing :
when app runs , the color of button changes continuously (for example every 3sec) without any touching or focusing , to catch clients eyes for clicking on it.
is there any way to do that?

Comment: Oh yes, but what have you tried ?

Comment: use `Handler` or `runOnUi thread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override 
  public void run() 
  {
     int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
     if(rnd==0)
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     if(rnd==1)
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
     if(rnd==2)
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
     if(rnd==3)
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

     btn.invalidate();
     handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
   }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

Comment: what is invalidate(); ? eclipse doesnt recognize it

Comment: Try after removing it.

Comment: invalidate() is use for refreshing the view

Comment: the color changes to blue once , then it doesnt change to other colors

Comment: Replace btn.invalidate(); in place of invalidate();

Comment: it doesnt change the color of button anymore

Comment: @PouyaHeydari, I found the solution, add handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000); after Runnable(){...}: is over.

Comment: any idea for android?

Answer (score 0):

**For repeating colors -**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    if (i == 0) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    i++;
    } else if (i == 1) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    i++;
    } else if (i == 2) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    i++;
    } else if (i == 3) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    i = 0;
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); // Set time in milliseconds
}
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 3000); // Set time in milliseconds
```

This code changes the color of button every 3 seconds in this order - Yellow, Red, Blue, Green.

**For RANDOM colors -**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    int i = (int) Math.random() * 3;
    if (i == 0) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (i == 1) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (i == 2) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (i == 3) {
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); // Set time in milliseconds
}
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 3000); // Set time in milliseconds
```

If you like this answer, please mark it as `selected`.

Comment: thank , but the color changes to blue once , then it doesnt change to other colors

Comment: @PouyaHeydari remove `invalidate()` please

Answer (score 0):

In drawable xml file declare an animation

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
etc...
</animation-list>
```

And then In code you can write

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.movie);
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)   
imageView.getBackground();
anim.start();
```